# SignIn Form FadeIn/Out

Tags: fadein, fadeout

Reference Image https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36614618/Doubts/Signin.jpg

I have a Problem. By default, Form in the image above will be hide. When I click on Signin Button(top right). Below form should get displayed. When I click on Signin Button again(top right) or outside the form. Below form should get hide.

Above concept is working, but the problem is when I click on Signin Btn, form gets opened, but when I click inside the form, form getting hide.

//TILL NOW MY CODE IS BELOW:

```
$('#signInFormDiv').hide(); //default form is hide.

$('#signInBtn').click(function(){ //when clicked on signin, form get displayed
$('#signInFormDiv').fadeToggle('fast');
return false;
});

$(':not(#signInBtn)').click(function(){ //when clicked on document, form get hide.
$('#signInFormDiv').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Comment: Stop switching between `hide()` `toggle()` you can just use one throughout, if you use `style="display:none"` attribute to have a hidden element to begin with, you can then just use `toggle` all the way through, and save you from having to keep track.

Comment: and the reason the for is getting hidden, is that the controls inside your `#signInBtn` are getting focussed, and they don't have the id `#signInBtn` maybe!

Answer (score 0):

would you use a flag to check if you're inside signin form?

```
var imOnsignIn = false;

$('#signInFormDiv').hide(); //default form is hide.
$('#signInFormDiv').hover(function(){ 
    imOnsignIn = true;  //I'm on the sign in form
}, function(){ 
    imOnsignIn = false; //I'm out...
});

$('#signInBtn').click(function(){ //when clicked on signin, form get displayed
    $('#signInFormDiv').fadeToggle('fast');
    return false;
});

$(':not(#signInBtn)').click(function(){ //when clicked on document, form get hide.
   if (!imOnsignIn){
      $('#signInFormDiv').fadeOut('fast');
   }
});
```

Comment: may it help you, but this doesn't works on touch screens (tablets, etc) where we cannot hover.